# Bulk insert using mongo through Lambda timeout and insert data 3 times

Tags: mongodb, aws-lambda

We have need to insert data into mongo from S3. We wrote a Lambda function which simply read file from S3 (JSON File) and using Mongoose just execute InsertMany. When we execute this lambda. Our mongodb insert take round about 7-10 minutes for 10K records. I need help on following

- Improve mongo Insert so we can insert 20k records < 5 minutes to avoid lambda timeout

I am already using Ordered:False to expedite insert in mongo

Answer (score 0):

Use native mongoDB client instead of Mongoose solves the problem. Seems like InsertMany perform better with native mongoDB compare to mongoose